# Linux/CentOS how to permanent inititate DHCP Client any reboot?

Tags: linux, centos, boot, dhcp

In my CentOS, i need to run `dhclient -v` command at every time i start/reboot the server. How to make this permanent please?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In CentOS, put the following into `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ethX`:

```
DEVICE=ethX
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
ONBOOT=yes
HWADDR=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

Of course change `ethX` to your interface name (`eth0`, `eth1` or similar).

Similarly, change `HWADDR` to yours interface MAC address. You can see it by looking at the output of `ifconfig -a` command (the part after `HWaddr` keyword).

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar issue. dhclient wouldn't start on boot, even though the config looked to be correct.
After a while i remembered that this is case sensitive.

`BOOTPROTO=DHCP`

will not start your dhclient on boot.

`BOOTPROTO=dhcp`

The value needs to be lowercase.

Comment: What file should this be in?